MPV Startup Delay Issue on Raspberry Pi Lite OS Due to HDMI Display Delay
I am experiencing an issue on my Raspberry Pi running Raspberry Pi Lite OS.
Problem: When I boot the Raspberry Pi, the TV is powered on, but the screen does not display the output immediately. The screen only turns on after I use the TV remote to wake it up.
Impact: As a result, MPV (which I have set to start automatically at boot) does not play my media because it starts before the HDMI display is fully recognized and turned on.
I need a solution to either:
Delay the MPV startup until the TV is fully detected and the screen is active.
Or force the display to be recognized before MPV starts, ensuring smooth playback without delay.
I have tried the following, but the issue persists:
HDMI Force Hotplug (hdmi_force_hotplug=1 in /boot/config.txt).
TV Service: Commands like tvservice -s don't seem to provide useful information (command not found or error messages).
vcgencmd Commands: I get errors when trying to query the status of the display with vcgencmd.
I am looking for suggestions, workarounds, or scripts that can help resolve this HDMI detection delay issue.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
